# conditional regex - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, conditional-statements

I want to remove number containing between 6 and 8 digits, so the regex I am using is:
**\b\d{6,8}**

It works fine, but, it if I have two numbers separated by an underscore (_), for example **1234567890_12345678901234567890**
I want it removed as well.
I must use \b (boundary).

To me it seems like a condition:

match numbers between 6 and 8 digit, but if you see two numbers separated by an underscore match them too (regardless of the number of digits in each number).

> match: 12345678
>
> match: 12345678934567_1234567890123456789
>
> match: 123_23
>
> no match: 12345

I need a single regex that handles both cases.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\b(?:\d{6,8}|\d+_\d+)\b
```

It is simply 6 to 8 digits or any number_number.

[Click here](https://regex101.com/r/wF6eE7/6) to see it in action.

Comment: Hi Neil,
I can't use the last \b, I need something that will work without the last \b

Thanks

Comment: @AsafCohen If you remove the last \b, then it will match numbers larger than 8 digits.  If it is followed by letters rather than numbers, then you could also replace `\b` with `(?:[^_\d]|$)`.  [See here](https://regex101.com/r/wF6eE7/7).

Comment: This is what I needed.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use this

```
^(\d+_\d+)|(\d{6,8})$
```

This regex contains two parts:

1. `(\d+_\d+)` covers cases with "_" symbol;
2. `(\d{6,8})` covers other cases

Comment: That would match `______`, `_1234_`, etc.

Comment: You don't need character class in `[\d]`

Comment: @Tushar, thanks for this notice. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one as well:

```
\b\d+(?:\d{4,6}|_)\d+\b
```

And if you'd like to allow more than one `_` characters, try this one:

```
\b\d+(?:\d{4,6}|_[\d_]*)\d+\b
```

This second one will match on this too: `12345678934567_1234567890_123456789`